# Regex find characters in string

Tags: regex

Given the following string

```
2010-01-01XD2010-01-02XX2010-01-03NX2010-01-04XD2010-01-05DN
```

I am trying to find all instances of the date followed by one or two characters ie `2010-01-01XD` but not where the characters are `XX`

I have tried

```
(2010-01-02[^X]{2})|(2010-01-08[^X]{2})|(2010-01-07[^X]{2})|(2010-01-05[^X]{2})|(2010-01-15[^X]{2})
```

this works if both chars are not `X`. I have also tried

```
(2010-01-02[^X]{1,2})|(2010-01-08[^X]{1,2})|(2010-01-07[^X]{1,2})|(2010-01-05[^X]{1,2})|(2010-01-15[^X]{1,2})
```

this works for for `DX` but not `XD`

So trying to be a little clearer

```
2010-01-01XD
2010-01-01DX
2010-01-01ND
```

All above should be picked up

```
2010-01-01XX
```

And this ignored

Comment: Do you want to match any date, or only a specific date?

Comment: The specific dates in a list also i would like to thank everyone for the answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex based on negative lookahead:

```
(20[0-9]{2}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?!XX)[A-Z]{2})
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vX4nX0/1)

Comment: While nice, lookaheads kill performance, and aren't needed for a case this simple. I would go with the shorter, faster and easier to read method I demonstrated.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - I don't agree in this case that a lookahead is slower than a series of alternations. And these kind of regex are never readable anyway unless you get a regex formatter [RegexFormat](http://www.regexformat.com) to help.

Comment: I agree with @sln: The negative look ahead is the way to go. Favour readability over "performance" (I doubt there would be noticeable difference in performance anyway). Same goes for unnecessary non-capturing groups - unless there's a performance problem, just capture - it's less regex noise.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use a lookahead assertion (if available).

```
 # (2010-01-01|2010-01-02|2010-01-08|2010-01-07|2010-01-05|2010-01-15)(?!XX)(?i:([a-z]){1,2})

 (                        # (1 start), One of these dates
      2010-01-01
   |  2010-01-02
   |  2010-01-08
   |  2010-01-07
   |  2010-01-05
   |  2010-01-15
 )                        # (1 end)
 (?! XX )                 # Look ahead assertion, cannot match XX here
 (?i:                     # 1 or 2 of any U/L case letter
      ( [a-z] ){1,2}           # (2)
 )
```

Comment: Hmm... Why are the dates fixed?

Comment: I just used his example.

Answer (score 2):

You could likely use a simple pattern with a negtive lookahead such as this:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?!XX)[A-Z]{1,2}
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/dI1nW4/2

To allow Unicode characters (with the exception of XX) you could use:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?!XX)\D{1,2}
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/yB5fI0/1

Comment: Note: for one to two characters use `{1,2}` at the end.

Comment: If there can be one or two character, using `.` is wrong, since it can gobble up the start of the next entry.

Comment: @nhahtdh, Please provide an example; for it didn't 'gobble up' anything on my end.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/yB5fI0/1 (If people just plainly modify your current regex by changing `{2}` to `{1,2}`)

Comment: `\D` does fix the problem. Just a note: `\D` matches everything in the Unicode, except for 0-9 ASCII digits, so it's best that you restrict it to `[A-Z]`

Answer (score 1):

```
20[0-9]{2}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]([A-Z][A-WYZ]|[A-WYZ][A-Z])
```

[See it in action](http://www.regexr.com/39hdt).

Answer (score 0):

A negative look ahead is the easiest way to assert the letters *not* being `XX`, but there are some simplifications you can make to the alternation by recognising the parts of the date shared by all dates you're trying to match, making this shorter regex:

```
2010-01-(02|08|07|05|15)(?!XX)[A-Z]{1,2}
```